# Qt convert data to QPixmap

Tags: c++, qt, qpixmap, qvector

Im trying to convert some data from QVector to QBitmap. How can I do this?
I have a QVector of QPointF, and Im trying to convert that data to redraw on QPixmap.

```
QVector<QPointF> data;
QPixmap pixMap;
```

EDIT

I've made something like this. Why it isn't work?

```
QPainter *painter = new QPainter(&pixMap);
for(int i = 1; i < data.last().x(); i++){
  painter->setPen(QPen(Qt::black, 2));
  painter->drawPolyline(this->data.data(), this->data.size());
}
  delete painter;
  setPixmap(pixMap);
```

Comment: You need to draw points on a pixmap?

Comment: Yes :) Sorry for not exactly explanation

Comment: @Shepherd Have you taken a look at `QPainter`?

Comment: What is "`this->data.data()`" and "`this->data.size()`". What is "`data.last.x()`"?

Comment: You have above what is data. Generally data() function gets all QPOINTF from Vector and in that way I can repaint on WIDGET. But when I did it on QPixMap, nothing apeard.

Answer (score 0):

You can just draw into a pixmap using `QPainter`:

```
QPixmap pixmap(100,100);   // a pixmap of size 100x100 pixels
QPainter painter(&pixmap);

// iterate over your points and draw them using the painter
```

[`QPainter`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpainter.html) docs have loads of examples on how to draw stuff using QPainter, brushes, pens...

Comment: I am sorry, that is not a good question - what didn't work? How didn't it work? What did the compiler say?

Comment: Note that the QPixmap state isn't guaranteed to be updated fully until the QPainter object is destroyed.  The easiest way to guarantee that is to put the QPainter (and the drawing commands called on it) inside a set of curly braces, with QPixmap declared outside that scope, and don't try to use the QPixmap for anything until after the end of the scope (i.e. after the close-curly-brace)